# End Using SqlConnection Kills my global sqlConnection connection string

Tags: vb.net, class, using, sqlconnection, class-library

I have a global class setup as

```
Public Class ReqGlobal
  Private Shared _sqlConn As SqlClient.SqlConnection

  Public Shared Property SqlConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Get
        Return _sqlConn
    End Get
    Set(value As SqlClient.SqlConnection)
        _sqlConn = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Private Sub New()
    ' Prevents users from making this an instance
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then on my form I would run the following code:

```
Dim sqlConn as SqlConnection = ReqGlobal.SqlConnection
Using conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = sqlConn 
            conn.Open()
            Using bulkCopy As SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy = New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(conn)
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tableName"

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)
            End Using
End Using
```

Now when it gets to End Using it clears the connection string in **conn** as it should, but it also is some how clearing the connection string in **ReqGlobal.SqlConnection**

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here  and why its clearing the connection string in both places, please. This is a Class Library if that matters.

Comment: A `shared` connection? Ugh! You have a connection-pool by default which manages physical connections under the hood. No need for a `shared` connection which can cause several issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `SqlConnection` is a reference type, when you assign `conn` in the using statement the actual global connection is used and not a copy.
When the using scope ends `Disposed` is called on the global connection and it becomes useless.
You should not use a global connection like this for thread safety issues (among others).

I would recommend either creating a new connection in the using statement with the connection string from the global class, or calling a method in the global class that creates the connection.

```
Public Class ReqGlobal
   private shared _cnnStr As string = "someConnectionString"

   Public Shared Function GetConnection() As DbConnection
      Dim con = new SqlClient.SqlConnection(_cnnStr)
      con.Open()
      return con
   End Function

End Class
```

Usage

```
Using conn As DbConnection = ReqGlobal.GetConnection()
...
End Using
```

Answer (score 3):

`End Using` calls the `Dispose` method on your global connection object, therefor you won't be able to use it afterwards.

Don't use a global connection. Instead, initialize the conneciton string on a global level and create a new `SqlConnection` object every time you want to execute a query:

```vb
Using connection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString)
    ' Your code
End Using
```